# show result of ajax request by modifying html after .ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am executing an ajax request. Depending on success or error a information should be shown to the user. Therefore are two templates available. If I use this code, the templates are not shown, because the code is already executed before ajax is ready, and chose the corresponding template.

```
var template;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/insert.inc.php",
    
    data: { 
        frmData: $("#frmData").serialize(),
        selected_members: selected_members
    },          
    
    success:function(data) {
        console.log('success: ' + data);                    
        if(data == "1") {
            meldung = $("#success").html(); 
        }
        else {
            meldung = $("#error").html();    
        }                       
    },
    error: function(data) {
            meldung = $("#error").html();
    }
});         
$("#div_msg").html(meldung);
$("#div_msg").slideDown("slow");
```

Is the only solution to put the last two lines into the error and success function both?

Comment: You can use the `complete` option to pass a method that will be executed after the `success` or `error` callbacks have finished: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: yes, cause that it when you want that code to be executed

Comment: @yainspan Top!!